# parcel build error: plugin is not a function

Tags: bundler, parcel

I am trying to build a simple web project

project structure like this

```
-src
--index.html
--index.js
--style.css
package.json
yarn.lock
```

I installed parcel-bundler with this

`yarn global add parcel-bundler`

And I run the parcel build command

`parcel build src/index.html`

But error has occurred followed by this log

```
D:\playground\js\sample>parcel build src/index.html
×  D:\playground\js\sample\src\style.css:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function
    at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.14.0\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:288:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.14.0\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:212:26)
    at C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.14.0\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:254:14 
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.14.0\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:250:23)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.14.0\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:17)
```

I'm just following the instruction of parcel's official docs

I cannot find a solution

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: parcel-bundler is deprecated. Use 'parcel' not 'parcel-bundler'

Comment: Not according to the official website? https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

Comment: @Kokodoko https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-bundler It's deprecated... not the first time the documentation has been a pain point for me. Starting to regret trying to use parcel ngl.

Comment: See my answer below. Some of us can't (though would love to) use Parcel 2 yet, because they've refused to support Vue 2 SFCs, which again are not upgradable to Vue 3 due to dependencies...

Answer (score 16):

#### Try --no-minify

Why is the accepted answer, "throw out the baby with the bathwater?"

parcel-bundler does still work, but instead of fixing what's broken, it's been abandoned for Parcel 2, which **DOES NOT** support Vue 2 SFCs.

Building a Rails 6/Vue 2 app and converting to parcel from webpack(er), so Parcel 2 is not an option for me. (Demanding people upgrade, and then not providing an upgrade path or decent docs, reminds me too much of webpack!)

`parcel build ./app/packs/entrypoints/*.js --no-minify`

This disables minification, which at least eliminates this particular error for me.

Comment: ...thanks for this. Useful not least because parcel v2 has issues of its own! (...and I want to publish without spending a day figuring out the changes since last time).

Answer (score -1):

**package.json**
If you have preset the scripts...

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
```

...simply run

```
npm run build
```

otherwise use this syntax:

```
npm run build index.html
```

Replace index.html to whatever file you want to build, but make sure it is the same type of file.

Comment: when used parcel build index.html had this error, but configured in package.json as said worked.